# Group array data by array element in php

Tags: php, arrays, group-by

Here is my array that is put together:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 1335848400000
                [value] => 1
                [product_id] => 1
                [title] => Test Product
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 1338526800000
                [value] => 8
                [product_id] => 1
                [title] => Test Product
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 1335848400000
                [value] => 1
                [product_id] => 2
                [title] => Test Product 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 1338526800000
                [value] => 4
                [product_id] => 2
                [title] => Test Product 2
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 1338526800000
                [value] => 6
                [product_id] => 3
                [title] => Test Product 3
            )

    )

)
```

What I would like it to display as:

```
{
name: 'Test Product',
data: [[1335848400000, 1],[1338526800000, 8]]
},
{
name: 'Test Product 2',
data: [[1335848400000, 1], [1338526800000, 4]]
},
{
name: 'Test Product 3',
data: [[1338526800000, 6]]
},
```

I need to group by dates and values together as such for highcharts.

How would I go about doing that?  I have no idea where to even start.  I have done research into it but couldn't find a good example.

EDIT:

Working code except with one error:

```
for($i=0 ; $i<=count($array) ; $i++)
                    {
                    $result_array[$i]['name'] = $array[$i][0]['title'];
                        for($j=0 ; $j<count($array[$i]) ; $j++)
                        {
                            $result_array[$i]['data'][$j][0] = $array[$i][$j]['date'];
                            $result_array[$i]['data'][$j][1] = $array[$i][$j]['value'];
                        }
                    }

                    echo $result = json_encode($result_array);
```

error:

Severity: Notice

Message:  Undefined offset: 0

Filename: name.php

Line Number: 115

```
[{"name":null},{"name":"Test Product","data":[[1335848400000,"1"],[1338526800000,"8"]]},{"name":"Test Product 2","data":[[1335848400000,"1"],[1338526800000,"4"]]},{"name":"Test Product 3","data":[[1338526800000,"6"]]}]
```

Comment: there must be like a hundred similar questions like this.

Comment: Have you tried `usort()`, `array_walk()`, and `json_encode()`? I think that would be a good starting point.

Comment: Do you literally want `[[1335848400000, 1], [1338526800000, 4]]` or is this shorthand for a subarray?

Comment: I literally want [[1335848400000, 1], [1338526800000, 4]]

Comment: The general answer to all these questions is *write your own*. However, PHP has dozens of [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) that will likely help (like those noted by **Tim Withers**). But you are unlikely to find a single, *magic* function to output such a specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this loop

```
<?php

for($i=1 ; $i<=count($main_array) ; $i++)
{
   $result_array[$i]['name'] = $main_array[$i][0]['title'];
   for($j=1 ; $j<=count($main_array[$i]) ; $j++)
   {
       $result_array[$i]['data'][$j][0] = $main_array[$i][$j]['date'];
       $result_array[$i]['data'][$j][1] = $main_array[$i][$j]['value'];
   }
}


echo $result = json_encode($result_array);

?>
```

I have tested it... It works compaletely as you want

Comment: {"1":{"name":"Test Product","data":[1338526800000,"8"]},"2":{"name":"Test Product 2","data":[1338526800000,"4"]},"3":{"name":"Test Product 3","data":[1338526800000,"6"]}}

Comment: This is what it is giving me, but I need it to be: {"1":{"name":"Test Product","data":[1335848400000, 1], [1338526800000,"8"]},"2":{"name":"Test Product 2","data":[1335848400000, 1], [1338526800000,"4"]},"3":{"name":"Test Product 3","data":[1338526800000,"6"]}}

Comment: okay will you give some time?

Comment: of course! any help is much appreciated

Comment: thank you!!!! I am getting an undefined offset of 0 at $mainarray[$1][0]['title'];  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry I didn't getting what are you saying please update in question

Comment: And ya if any answer is helpful to you then give 1+ up and answere is true then make it rightso it can be helpful to others also..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12611/discussion-between-k-g-and-hardik)